# airflow webserver -p 8080 result in OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow

**After installing airflow package in AWS EC2 instance , i am trying to start the airflow webserver Its showing permission denied issue , i am not getting which file or folder its trying to create/modify to get this error.**

```
[root@ip-172-31-62-1 airflow]# /usr/local/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080
[2017-06-13 04:24:35,692] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
[2017-06-13 04:24:36,093] [4053] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/ec2-user/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 791, in webserver
    gunicorn_master_proc = subprocess.Popen(run_args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied



------------------------------------
The Value of run_args in above error message is 
['gunicorn', '-w', '4', '-k', 'sync', '-t', '120', '-b', '0.0.0.0:8080', '-n', 'airflow-webserver', '-p', '/home/ec2-user/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid', '-c', 'airflow.www.gunicorn_config', '--access-logfile', '-', '--error-logfile', '-', 'airflow.www.app:cached_app()']
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. It got resolved when I installed the whole setup in sudo mode. Please find the commands I used:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade

sudo apt-get install python-pip

sudo -H pip install airflow

sudo airflow initdb

sudo airflow webserver -p 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and the existing answer wouldn't work for me because the user didn't have sudo permissions. What worked for me was adding bin to the path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Or in my case:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

Then I could just run:

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

Instead of:

```
.local/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080
```